# Pixel correlations from two raster datasets in R

Tags: raster, r, correlation

I am having trouble calculating the pixel by pixel correlation coefficient between two datasets. My current code takes in two folders full of rasters and creates two independent raster stacks. These rasters all have the same cellsize and extent. I then try and take the correlation coefficient (spearman in my case) between the column values of those rasters.

```
library(raster)

r <- raster()
raster1 <- list.files(path = "data/List1", pattern = "*.tif$", full.names = T)
raster2 <- list.files(path = "data/List2", pattern = "*.tif$", full.names = T)
l1 <- stack(raster1)
l2 <- stack(raster2)

list1Values <- values(l1)
list2Values <- values(l2)
corValues <- vector(mode = 'numeric')

for (i in 1:dim(list1Values)[1]){
  corValues[i] <- cor(x = list1Values[i,], y = list2Values[i,], method = 'spearman')
}

corRaster <- setValues(r, values = corValues)
```

However at the correlation for loop it gives six error messages saying

```
In cor(x = list1Values[i, ], y = list2Values[i, ], method = "spearman") :
  the standard deviation is zero
```

Ignoring that and continuing on, the last line errors out saying

```
Error in setValues(r, values = corValues) : 
  length(values) is not equal to ncell(x), or to 1
```

My initial guess was that since the datasets have a lot of NA values (In this case it is a lot of open ocean that there is no data for), that could cause problems, so I added the

```
use = "complete.obs"
```

parameter to the cor function. This errors saying

```
Error in cor(x = list1Values[i, ], y = list2Values[i, ], method = "spearman",  : 
  no complete element pairs
```

My guess is that this last error is telling me the matrices it created don't line up, and no non-NA cells match. I have no clue how this is possible because I have been working with these rasters for years and they certainly line up. Other than that, I don't know why this isn't working.

---

This question is not a duplicate of [Correlation/relationship between map layers in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278982) in any way. First I am not using point data, but instead raster. I am also interested in a simple pearson and/or spearman correlation coefficient NOT cross correlation nor spatial correlation. I'm also not using two layers, but two sets of hundreds of layers (making the statistical analysis of the correlation valid). Lastly, this code is doing fundamentally different things than that post and I am asking for specific help with the errors arising.

Comment: This issue was addressed just last week. In the future, please search the site before posting. Also note that you are approaching this in the same way as the previous OP, which is not correct. A correlation of two values is nonsensical.

Comment: I will look into that issue, however note that when I did search (and I had searched for about a week prior) this particular one never showed up. Also note, this has nothing to do with a correlation of just two rasters. I have several hundred that I am correlating, and this analysis is absolutely valid.

Comment: Your code indicates that you are looking a pair-wise correlations cor(x = list1Values[i,], y = list2Values[i,]). When searching for R related content use [R] in the search term as the brackets specify the term using the letter.

Comment: Sorry, I initially flagged the incorrect duplicate and thought that I had fixed it (apparently not). Please look at this one: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277575/how-to-do-spatial-correlation-between-two-sets-of-rasters-in-r?noredirect=1#comment442580_277575

Comment: Try this and just ignore the SD errors: corValues <- rep(NA,ncell(l1)); "or(i in 1:nrow(list1Values)) {corValues[i] <- cor(list1Values[i,], list2Values[i,], method = 'spearman')}"; cor.raster <- l1[[1]]; cor.raster[] <- NA; cor.raster[] <- corValues

Comment: @Jeffrey Evans I have placed those lines in the code (assuming the open quote is actually an 'f' and the end quote is a mistake). I replaced the numeric mode and previous for loops. All the lines run, still seeing the SD errors, and when I try to assign the values to a raster (last line of my previous code), it still errors out saying the length is not equal to ncell(x) or to 1. I'm not exactly sure what some of those lines do as working with rasters in R is new to me.

Comment: Look at the bottom of the post i linked in my above comment. It skips creating unnecessary objects entirely. You will have to ignore the sd error, it is likely coming from identical values.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. That loop is definitely running, however very very slowly. I have 32,058 cells in the rasters and through some print statements it is completing about one cell every four seconds. That means it will complete this correlation calculation in 89 days. Would converting the stacked rasters to vectors before the loop improve processing speed?

Comment: You cannot take print statements within a for loop literally, they are absolutely no measure of performance benchmarking or processing time. A problem with 32,058 is not that big and should finish in a reasonable time all-be-it a few hours. What will slow it down is the number of layers in each stack. If they are huge, >1000 layers, then you may want to extract the data but, you may run into memory problems. If you really want an efficient method, extract the data into two data.frame objects and then use mapply. The NA's should be retained and the resulting vector the same length as the raster

Comment: Ill look into extracting to data frames and mapply, although i've never used it. Currently my raster list is only 25 long (in each dataset) but that is just for testing, I'm looking at ~750 for real analysis. When I did convert to vector before the loop, it ran, but all the values were NA. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading what you're trying to do correctly, a more robust approach would be to use `raster::calc()` on your stacked layers, as follows. This allows on-disk calculations as well as the option to speed things up with parallel processing.

```
# combine your two raster stacks. Now layers 1:(n/2) will be 
# correlated with layers ((n/2)+1):n. Make sure both stacks have the same 
# number of layers, i.e. nlayers(l_all) is even!
l_all <- stack(l1, l2)

# write a little function to do the correlation. The input is the vector
# of values at cell n, which has length() == nlayers(l_all)
corvec <- function(vec = NULL) {
  cor(
    # 'top' half of stack
    x      = vec[1:(length(vec)/2)],
    # 'bottom' half of stack
    y      = vec[((length(vec)/2) + 1):length(vec)],
    use    = 'complete.obs',
    method = 'spearman'
  )
}

corlyrs <- calc(
  l_all,
  fun = function(x) {
    # handle areas where all cell vals are NA, e.g. ocean
    if (all(is.na(x))) {
      NA_real_
    } else {
      corvec(vec = x)
    }
  }
)
```

The above will return a rasterLayer of correlation values. It took about 30s to correlate 2 sets of 6 300x300 cell rasters on my laptop.

To speed things up with clusterR,

```
# keep a cpu or two spare
cpus <- max(1, (parallel::detectCores() - 1))
beginCluster(n = cpus)
corlyrs <- clusterR(x         = l_all,
                    fun       = calc,
                    args      = list(fun = function(cell) {
                      if (all(is.na(cell))) {
                        NA_real_
                      } else {
                        corvec(cell)
                      }
                    }),
                    export    = 'corvec'
                    )
endCluster()
```

The last option may not be worth it unless your rasters are quite large. Saved me about 10 seconds on the actual calc, according to microbenchmark, but it also took about that long to establish the cluster. Benefits are much clearer with big rasters.

Comment: That is beautiful. I haven't messed around with the clusterR, but the base code works flawlessly. I did a pearson correlation to test the accuracy (against python code which can do this calculation except only for pearson) and the output rasters match EXACTLY. I'm fairly certain the approach Jeffery and I were eventually getting to would work as well, but this doesn't present any of the current problems. Thank you so much!

Comment: You do not have to do NA handling with the cor function. In this case NA begets NA eg., cor(c(NA,NA,NA),c(NA,NA,NA)) so, it is necessary code, albeit, good coding practice. BTW, @maj, as indicated a clear answer was on the post I linked. You can easily index the stack(s) and pipe into an empty raster. The use of multithreading is a nice addition here though.

Comment: @orbl_soil again, this is great. I am just trying to understand exactly what it is doing. I think I understand the function itself - just getting the first half of the raster stack and correlating it with the second half, but I start to lose it when the function is actually called. Specifically after specifying the raster object to be calculated on, why is there a function(x)? Wouldn't that normally just be fun = corvec? Also, I'm trying to get a bit of feedback from the loops, by seeing what cell or something its on, but I can't find a place for it within the calculation.

Comment: @maj all good - `corvec()` as written will fall over on a cell where the whole stack is NA values, even though as @JeffreyEvans points out, `cor()` on its own looks like it should be able to handle that. More here but tbh I'm not clear on the root cause - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716967/getting-error-using-cor-in-for-loop-in-r-for-list-of-csv-files#23717218. I've just gotten used to adding in that little if clause to handle all-NA input vectors. I don't think there's a way to build in progress monitoring without using some kind of add-on package unfortunately.

Comment: (also the NA-handling could just as easily have been built into `corvec()` instead of writing the function(x) part in calc, but I forgot I needed it until the last minute)

Comment: @orbl_soil Thanks! I'll keep looking into that link as well.

Comment: Also, cor() does work and the code @JefferyEvans was working on also seems to work, but it takes enormous amounts of time - on the order of weeks to months for just one of my datasets.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, here is an approach, in memory, that uses `mapply`. This is one of the lesser known apply functions in R that lets you apply a function across objects.

Here, when I create objects from the raster stacks, I wrap the `stack` function call in `list` and `values`. This results in list objects, containing data.frames holding the raster values. This makes the data ready for `mapply`, which expects list objects. The use of sapply allows me to use a numeric row index `1:nrow(s1[[1]])` to aggregate the row-by-row correlations. This results in a vector of correlations, matching the rows in each lists data.frames. This vector is ordered to the cells in the source rasters and can be piped directly back into a source raster.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
  s1 <- list(values( stack(r, r*0.15, r/1805.78) ))
  s2 <- list(values( stack(r^2, r/0.87*10, r/sum(values(r),na.rm=T)) ))

r[] <- as.vector(mapply(function(X,Y) { sapply(1:nrow(s1[[1]]), function(row) 
               cor(X[row,], Y[row,]))}, X=s1, Y=s2))
plot(r)
```